# Unable to use 'where' when using 'timestampdiff' in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to execute the following function.

```
%%sql SELECT Dog_Guid, start_time, end_time, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, start_time, end_time) AS Duration
from exam_answers
where Duration > 0
order by duration desc
limit 10
```

And I am producing this error:

> (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (1054, "Unknown column 'Duration' in 'where clause'") [SQL: 'SELECT Dog_Guid, start_time, end_time, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, start_time, end_time) AS Duration\nfrom exam_answers\nwhere Duration > 0\norder by duration desc\nlimit 10']

Is this because I can't use `where` on an alias or because I can't use `where` on derived columns? I don't see what I'm doing wrong here. What I'd like to do is just output all the columns that are `0` are greater (the column does have null values also, hence...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use an alias  in where  clause

```
SELECT Dog_Guid, start_time, end_time, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, start_time, end_time) AS Duration
from exam_answers
 where TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, start_time, end_time) > 0
 order by duration desc
 limit 10
```

the where clause is processed  before than the select clause  .. so at the moment of where processing the alias  is not know

For details, see the manual "[Problems with Column Aliases](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-alias.html)".

Comment: Sorry about that, I tried clicking accept as soon as you answered, hence the upvote. But I had a 15 minute waiting time before accepting.

Comment: And the link to the manual that explains it: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-alias.html